# Retrieve Data from 3rd table

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server

I have 3 tables named **Companies**, **Products** and **Batch**.

**Company table** mainly has **comp_id, and comp_name** as attributes.

**Products Table** has **Prod_id, Prod_name and comp_id** as a **Foreign key** from Products Table.

**Batch Table** has **Batch_id, Prod_id_fk** as a foreign key from Products Table along with many other attributes.

Now, Basically what i want to do is that i want that it would be a better for me that if i could get retrieve Comp_id from Batch Table.

Note: Comp_id is not in Batch table, but batch table has prod_id_fk and each prod_id is related to company.

I have no guess to do this. Please help.

In more simple words, Table A is linked to Table B and Table B is Linked to Table  C. And i want to get data of A from C by querying on C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can join the `Products` and `Batch` tables to get the values from `Products` (including `comp_id`) that are associated with each `Batch`. Here's a basic example that will return all values from `Batch` plus the associated `comp_id`.

```
SELECT b.*, p.comp_id
FROM Batch b
INNER JOIN Products p ON b.Prod_id_fk = p.Prod_id;
```

Performing joins is something that you'll probably need to do quite a bit of, when working with a relational database like SQL Server. I would highly recommend going through a beginner's tutorial on SQL databases, to get an idea of the basics needed for working with them.

Comment: What if i want to get Comp_name which is stored in Company Table.

Comment: As i also want to get company_name which is stored in company table. And Product table has foreign key relation with company table.

Comment: Please Reply me.

Comment: @JahanzaibNiazi Then you'll have to join that table into the query. This is absolute basic SQL, please take Elezar's advice, and learn at least a little about the subject. You need to have done research before asking questions, as described in ["How to ask"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I am at the edge of some thing lets say that i am trying to save myself from something thats why i asked such think in hurry. Deadline which i got to complete task is about to end and i have no idea how to do this,

Comment: I understand that, but this is a Q&A forum, not a support chatline. We're all doing other things, and aren't necessarily available to answer you immediately. Pestering us won't get a response quicker. In fact, it's more likely to annoy people, and result in no one responding at all. Anyway, the other answers that have been added show how to join multiple tables to get `comp_name` as well, so you should have your answer, now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use joins ! Simply join the Batch table with the Products table on the primary key of Products table(prod_id) with the foreign key in the Batch table(prod_id_fk), and then join the Products table with the Company table on the primary key of the Company table(comp_id) with the foreign key in the Products table(comp_id).

```
select b.batch_id, c.comp_name
from batch b
join products p
on b.prod_id_fk = p.prod_id
join company c
on c.comp_id = p.comp_id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from Batch batch inner join Products products on products.Prod_id = batch.Prod_id_fk
inner join  Company company on  company.comp_id = Products.comp_id
```

Comment: don't just paste the code, always try to explain the code or query. It will be more helpful.

Comment: I'm actually new here for helping. I hope I can improve soon. Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all i have solved.

```
SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT batch.batch_id, batch.product_id_fk, batch.quantity, batch.purchaseDate, batch.manufacturing_date, batch.expiryDate, batch.sold_qty, batch.left_qty, batch.packing, batch.p_price, batch.received_percentage, company.comp_name, products.p_name, products.p_id_pk FROM batch INNER JOIN products ON batch.product_id_fk = products.p_id_pk INNER JOIN company ON products.fk_com_id = company.comp_id where company.comp_id='" + id+ "'", con);
```

Comment: Don't get in the habit of using string concatenation to create your query, or your code will be vulnerable to SQL injection attacks, as well as runtime errors with unusual errors.

Answer (score 0):

use this

select c.*  from company c

inner join product p on p.comp_id=c.comp_id

inner join batch b on b.prod_id_fk=p.prod_id